# Preview tab for Eclipse Wikitext

Tags: eclipse, markdown, mylyn-wikitext

I used to be able to get a preview tab for Eclipse WikiText documents in Linux but in Neon it no longer appears. Is it possible to enable it for a Markdown file?

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce your problem in my Eclipse Neon. It works as expected:

[image: WikiText Editor]

1) have you opened the file with the appropriate Editor?

[image: Open With > WikiText Editor]

2) Is wikitext installed in your Eclipse?

In the "Eclipse Installation Details" windows (open it with the Help Menu), do you see the WikiText plugins?

[image: WikiText plugins - Eclipse Installation Details]

---

For Ubuntu (as discussed in [Bug 496323](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496323))

3) Is libwebkitgtk 3.0 installed?

Without libwebkitgtk the preview tab is missing:

[image: WikiText without preview tab under Linux Ubuntu]

Run

```
sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

Then everything works as expected:

[image: WikiText with preview tab under Linux Ubuntu]

Comment: I have checked and all the Mylyn Wikitext plugins are listed on my systems. The only thing it will do is show Markdown headers bolded in the Markdown source tab. There is no preview tab displayed at all. This has happened under both Eclipse Mars and Neon with a variety of downloads including Eclipse RCP/RAP, Eclipse Committers and Eclipse C/C++ under Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

Comment: I am not a Linux or Ubuntu user at all... This might be a bug on this OS only. Sometimes using GTK2 instead of GTK3 is something that can be tried (see [this article](https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/how-to-tell-if-you-are-running-eclipse-on-gtk2-or-on-gtk3/))

Comment: I moved from Mars to Neon because Mars was completely unusable under either GTK2 or GTK3. Neon under GTK3 has fixed all my known problems except for this if it actually related to GTK. I am not prepared to revert to GTK2 because of the large number of problems I experienced.

Comment: Looks like a bug (though I'm not able to reproduce on a mac).  It would be great if you'd file one at [bugs.eclipse.org, Mylyn/Mylyn Docs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Mylyn%20Docs)

Comment: Thanks to the input I got in Bug 496323, we have found a solution for you.

Comment: It turns out that libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 is needed with Eclipse Neon. It fixes problems using the Eclipse browser with GTK3 including this one. Do sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Per Jonathan's comment, the GTK webkit dependency must be installed, e.g.

`sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0`